# Storing data in Ram

Tags: java, store, ram

I ve got a problem in a game project. I develop a bot in video game. The game engine of the game is that the game gives every game tick information about the track and i use that information to make decisions about bot strategy. I want to store that information all these game ticks in a txt file. However, i noticed that when i store the data in txt files my bot fails to make correct decision. Actually the behavior of the bot slow down. Is there  efficient way to store my data to ram? My project is in java.

Comment: It sounds like you should work out *exactly* what's causing your bot to "fail to make correct decision" before moving the data.

Comment: How big is the data for each tick?

Comment: That depends on the structure of your data... You can use Java collections or a in-memory database

Comment: Without storing data my bot works fine. Every game tick i store 10 variables and all the game tick is approximately 60.000. I thought about using java collections i hope that is going to be a fast solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bot needs the data to make it's decision, it's best to keep all that data in ram.

If you need to save the data for other reasons to disk, you might want to consider only saving the data every minute, and not every game tick, as disk-io tends to be slow.

Comment: Yea i got it! i ll use two-dim vectors to store there the data and every min store itn to file. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

File writing is comparatively very slow, hence why your game slows down. What information exactly do you need to store? Defining a class (used statically, if necessary, but preferably not) whose members represent the data you need is probably a way to go about it...